# Performing a left join on multiple columns, one of which is a partial string

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to join by a) the first two characters of a first name, b) last name, and c) year. I was doing some reading on fuzzyjoin, but it doesn't seem like it's quite what I need.

I've tried

```
newly_joined_df <- names_df %>%
    left_join(values_df, by = c(substr("first_name", 1, 2), "last_name", "year")
```

And

```
newly_joined_df <- names_df %>%
    left_join(values_df, by = c(substr(names_df$first_name, 1, 2), "last_name", "year")
```

But both were dumb solutions, and threw obvious errors.

Comment: Paste or paste0?

Comment: Create the substring columns in each data frame first, i.e. with `mutate`.

Comment: Reproducible data please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(first_name_1st2char = substr(first_name, 1, 2)) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(first_name_1st2char = substr(first_name, 1, 2)), 
            by = c("first_name_1st2char", "last_name", "year")) %>%
  select(-first_name_1st2char)
```

**Output is:**

```
  first_name.x last_name year first_name.y age
1         john      asdf 2018          joe  12
2         jack    qwerty 2017         jake  34
```

**Sample data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(first_name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("jack", 
"john"), class = "factor"), last_name = structure(1:2, .Label = c("asdf", 
"qwerty"), class = "factor"), year = c(2018, 2017)), .Names = c("first_name", 
"last_name", "year"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(first_name = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("donald", 
"jake", "joe"), class = "factor"), last_name = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("asdf", "jong", "qwerty"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2018, 2017, 2018), age = c(12, 34, 5)), .Names = c("first_name", 
"last_name", "year", "age"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```